# How to add CSRF token in React native header

Tags: react-native

I have to include the CSRF token in my react native app. so how can I add and send it to laravel backend
headers:

```
{
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

Comment: What is the laravel version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can go inside the `<head>` tag

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

And here is the headers

```
headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.getElementsByName('csrf-token')[0].content
    },
```

Comment: Actually i'm passing it in React Native

Comment: You sent from react native but you still get toke error at the backend?

Answer (score 3):

you can added CSRF token in the request headers

```
headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
    },
```

Comment: Thank you @SRanuluge.. but i tried this method. before declaring the token variable in header how to create that particular token variable and how that variable pass the CSRF Token

Comment: please check this link ::https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451576/including-csrf-token-in-a-post-request-from-react-native-app?answertab=oldest#tab-top