# get csrf token in react native

Tags: django, reactjs, react-native, csrf

I have built django server to manage my data, then I have desktop react app where I can create new users/login/post data, it works flawless, It is based on csrf token verification and there is no problem with that. However I have also react-native app which is supposed to let user log in, and GET data which belongs to him. And here is question, how to get CSRF token in react native? In desktop app it looks more or less like this but I have no idea how to login in react native as I can't simply get Cookie with csrf token.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const csrfToken = Cookies.get('csrftoken')
    this.setState({csrfToken})

  }

    loginHandler = login_data => {
    this.setState({
      user: login_data.user,
      password: login_data.password
    }, () => {
      const auth = {
        "username": this.state.user,
        "password": this.state.password
      }

      fetch("http://localhost:8000/data/", {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": this.state.csrfToken,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(auth)
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(resp => console.log(resp))
        .then(() => this.getData())
        .catch(() => this.setState({
          user: "",
          passowrd: ""
        }))
    })
  };
```

Comment: doesn't need to be in cookie.. Accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542672/how-to-add-csrf-token-in-react-native-header/59542947#59542947 would be helpful

Comment: if you need that csrf token in subsequent api requests , just do withCredentials true in axios config

Comment: @overflow hi, but how can I set meta tag in react-native? In react.js it is easy but react-native doesn't have html with head to put there a tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add CSRF token in React native header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542672/how-to-add-csrf-token-in-react-native-header)

Comment: If your django app API only services mobile apps (react native) then you don't need CSRF protection at all for those APIs used by the app. That's because CSRF protects from forgery in browsers, not in apps. But if your api is also used in a browser, then you should create an endpoint to specifically fetch the csrf token (GET /api/csrftoken) with a Django view that returns the csrf token in json.

Comment: @dirkgroten it works! that was actually great idea and I didn't think about it to make Django serve token before... thank you so much for help:) Make an answer from that and i will mark it as a right answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two options:

- If your django app API only services mobile apps (react native) then you don't need CSRF protection at all for those APIs used by the app. That's because CSRF protects from forgery in browsers, not in apps.
- But if your api is also used in a browser, then you should create an endpoint to specifically fetch the csrf token (GET /api/csrftoken) with a Django view that returns the csrf token in json.