# How to manage mobile and web authentication with Django Rest and react/react native?

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native, django-rest-framework

We are in the process of setting up a project that requires mobile and web app authentication and were wondering if there are any best practices for implementation.

For the backend we are currently using django rest framework with a [knox token authentication](https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox) and for the web frontend react.js. For the future, there will be a mobile app in react native.

We want to set up the authentication now so that it supports the react native mobile app in the future. However, I have seen that Knox authentication does not work for mobile apps straight forward as it uses [csrf token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628605/get-csrf-token-in-react-native).

So I'm wondering if there are any best-practices for mobile app and web authentication that specifically feature good documentation, multi-device login and smooth extensibility of login options (fb, google etc) for the current setup drf and react.js/react native.

I'm grateful for any guiding hints.

Answer (score 2):

AWS Cognito seems to be a solution to your problem:

Typically, your users get tokens via an external UI provided by amazon (not really customizable) or by calling the Auth API within your React UI.

[image]

Cognito sends `access_token`, `id_token` and `refresh_token` to your react app. You need to pass the access_token to your drf backend (similar to knox token authentication) and validate it again via amazon.

Check out the [official docs for React](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js#option-1-use-pre-built-ui-components), check out [this tutorial for django](https://djangostars.com/blog/bootstrap-django-app-with-cognito/) (it helped me a lot!).