# csrf issue in fetch API call from react native

Tags: react-native, django-rest-framework, csrf, fetch-api, django-rest-auth

I am using the following code from react-native mobile application to make a social authentication call to dj-rest-auth local link. However my Facebook authentication succeeds each time and then the fetch (or axios) local API call executes, which runs perfectly for the first time/run returning me the token but thereafter on every other runs, it gives me an error saying missing or invalid csrf token. I can't used the Django docs getCookie function as it gives Document error since this is a react-native mobile application. Please guide how to properly have API calls using csrf from the mobile app, with the code being used below (which is inside an async function):

```
fetch(
    "http://192.168.1.102:8080/dj-rest-auth/facebook/",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
      },
      xsrfCookieName:"csrftoken",
      xsrfHeaderName:'X-CSRFToken',
      body:JSON.stringify({access_token:resolvedToken})
    }
  )
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  }  
  )
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

The logout function also give the missing or invalid csrf error, which is written below for reference:

```
async function Logout() {
  fetch(
    "http://192.168.1.102:8080/dj-rest-auth/logout/",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
      },
      xsrfCookieName:"csrftoken",
      xsrfHeaderName:'X-CSRFToken'
    }
    )
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => {console.log(data)})
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get csrf token in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628605/get-csrf-token-in-react-native)

Comment: @VasylNahuliak Nope. That question does not use django rest auth. For Django rest auth, if your remove the csrf then again you will get the same csrf missing or invalid error. Anyhow my code runs for the first time, which may mean that the csrf token is successfully sent to django server. But the issue is with the remaining further calls.

Comment: If you really need csrf token, you can try get their from cookies using this snippet https://gist.github.com/jqn/e6a2073e26f5db90a55664f53a1fcbad with https://github.com/react-native-cookies/cookies

Comment: @VasylNahuliak Thank you. I had seen the github link of react-native cookies. They have mentioned that they do not support Expo as it's using its own cookie support with a given link: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6756 . I now have a deadlock problem because the expo issue is still unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue above is resolved by removing "Session Authentication" from your default REST authentication classes in settings.py and keeping the "Basic Authentication" and "Token Authentication" enabled.

```
'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
```

Source: https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/164#issuecomment-860204677