# How to use csrf_token in Django RESTful API and React-Native?

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

I am trying to enable CSRF protection for a django - React Native application, I am familiar with the its process with React, from the django documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#ajax
I get an error from `if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "")`,  is there an alternate way to enable the csrf  apart from what is in this documentation or there is a change i need to make this piece of code

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

I am getting an error, with document

Comment: The link you provided is according to a deprecated doc version

Comment: Likely a duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59630762/18020941